# Batch/Powershell program to retrieve system info

Tags: powershell, batch

This is my first time coding! My intent for this program was to be able to give my technicians a flash drive that will pull system info and email it to me. Currently everything is working, but I was hoping for suggestions or tips on what I can improve on or add to it. I'm sure there is a lot of messy code that I got from Googling and jamming in there to fit my needs.

Any notes or help is super appreciated!

```
:: *** Get System Info.bat *** Version 1.0 *** 2021-10-22 *** Author: Boogershut ***
:: This batch file uses command line and PowerShell functions to retrieve system information, place it into a text file, and email the file for documentation.
:: Text file format: "'Account Name' 'Folder Number' - System Info_YearMonthDay-HourMinuteSecond"

    @echo off
    title Retrieving System Information
    
:: Variables
    set Cur_YYYY=&Rem Current Year
    set Cur_MM=&Rem Current Month
    set Cur_DD=&Rem Current Day
    set Cur_HH=&Rem Current Hour
    set Cur_Min=&Rem Current Minute
    set Cur_SS=&Rem Current Second
    set Cur_Date_Time=&Rem Current Date and Time set as YearMonthDay-HourMinuteSecond
    set AccountName=&Rem Account Name - defined by user
    set FolderNumber=&Rem Folder Number (Panel ID) - defined by user
    set FileName=&Rem Final File Name
    set TotalMem=&Rem Total amount of RAM installed
    set AvailableMem=&Rem Total amount of unused RAM
    set UsedMem=&Rem Total amount of used RAM
    set MemUsage=&Rem RAM being used shown as a percent
    set Count=&Rem Temporary counter variable used in Delayed Expansion
    set Var=&Rem Temporary variable used in Delayed Expansion

:: Assigning Date and Time Variables
    set Cur_YYYY=%date:~10,4%
    set Cur_MM=%date:~4,2%
    set Cur_DD=%date:~7,2%
    set Cur_HH=%time:~0,2%
    if %Cur_HH% lss 10 (set Cur_HH=0%time:~1,1%)
    set Cur_Min=%time:~3,2%
    set Cur_SS=%time:~6,2%
    set Cur_Date_Time=%Cur_YYYY%%Cur_MM%%Cur_DD%-%Cur_HH%%Cur_Min%%Cur_SS%
    
:: Assigning User Input Variables
    :LoopAccountName
        set /p AccountName=Input Account Name: 
        (echo %AccountName% | findstr /i /c:"name" /c:"@" /c:"{" /c:"}" /c:"=" >nul) && ((echo Account Name cannot contain "name" or special characters "@, {}, =") && (goto LoopAccountName)) || (goto LoopFolderNumber)
    :LoopFolderNumber
        set /p FolderNumber=Input Folder Number (Panel ID): 
        (echo %FolderNumber% | findstr /i /c:"name" /c:"@" /c:"{" /c:"}" /c:"=" >nul) && ((echo Folder Number cannot contain "name" or special characters "@, {}, =") && (goto LoopFolderNumber)) || (goto LoopStop)
    :LoopStop
    set FileName=%AccountName% %FolderNumber% - System Info_%Cur_Date_Time%
    
:: Display to user
    echo.
    echo Please wait - Retrieving "%AccountName% %FolderNumber%" System Information
    echo.
    
:: Create text file in current directory and input label
    echo %FileName% >> "%FileName%.txt"

:: Add date and time to file
    echo. >> "%FileName%.txt"
    echo __________________________________________________________________________________________________________________ >> "%FileName%.txt"
    echo. >> "%FileName%.txt"
    echo Info retreived on: >> "%FileName%.txt"
    cmd /c "date /t && time /t" >> "%FileName%.txt"

:: Run script to add Public IP Address to file
    echo. >> "%FileName%.txt"
    echo __________________________________________________________________________________________________________________ >> "%FileName%.txt"
    echo. >> "%FileName%.txt"
    if exist ".\ps.ps1" (PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '.\ps.ps1'") else (
        echo Unable to get Public IP Address. Script file not found. >> "%FileName%.txt"
        goto SkipPS
    )
    :SkipPS

:: Add PC info to file
        echo __________________________________________________________________________________________________________________ >> "%FileName%.txt"
        echo. >> "%FileName%.txt"
        echo System Information: >> "%FileName%.txt"
        echo. >> "%FileName%.txt"
        echo Current User: >> "%FileName%.txt"
        cmd /c "whoami" >> "%FileName%.txt"
    :: Add Serial Number to file
        echo. >> "%FileName%.txt"
        echo Serial Number/Service Tag: >> "%FileName%.txt"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set Count=1
        for /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F in (`cmd /c "wmic bios get serialnumber"`) do (
            set Var!Count!=%%F
            set /a Count=!Count!+1
        )
        echo %var2% >> "%FileName%.txt"
        endlocal
    :: Add CPU load to file
        echo. >> "%FileName%.txt"
        echo CPU Load: >> "%FileName%.txt"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set Count=1
        for /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F in (`cmd /c "wmic cpu get loadpercentage"`) do (
            set Var!Count!=%%F
            set /a Count=!Count!+1
        )
        for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%A in ('echo %var2% ') do set var2=%%A
        set var2=%var2:~0,-1%
        echo %var2%%% >> "%FileName%.txt"
        endlocal
    :: Add Memory Usage to file
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        for /f "tokens=4" %%A in ('systeminfo ^| findstr Physical') do if defined TotalMem (set AvailableMem=%%A) else (set TotalMem=%%A)
        set TotalMem=%TotalMem:,=%
        set AvailableMem=%AvailableMem:,=%
        set /a UsedMem=TotalMem-AvailableMem
        set /a MemUsage=(%UsedMem%*100)/%TotalMem%
        echo Memory Usage: >> "%FileName%.txt"
        echo %MemUsage%%% >> "%FileName%.txt"
        endlocal
    :: Add CPU details to file
        echo. >> "%FileName%.txt"
        echo CPU Info: >> "%FileName%.txt"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set Count=1
        for /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F in (`cmd /c "wmic cpu get name, numberofcores, status"`) do (
            set Var!Count!=%%F
            set /a Count=!Count!+1
        )
        echo %var1% >> "%FileName%.txt"
        echo %var2% >> "%FileName%.txt"
        endlocal
    :: Add Video card info to file
        echo. >> "%FileName%.txt"
        echo Video Card: >> "%FileName%.txt"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set Count=1
        for /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F in (`cmd /c "wmic path win32_VideoController get AdapterRAM, DeviceID, DriverVersion, Name, Status"`) do (
            set Var!Count!=%%F
            set /a Count=!Count!+1
        )
        echo %var1% >> "%FileName%.txt"
        echo %var2% >> "%FileName%.txt"
        endlocal
    :: Add ram details to file
        echo. >> "%FileName%.txt"
        echo RAM Info: >> "%FileName%.txt"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set Count=1
        for /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F in (`cmd /c "wmic memorychip get devicelocator, manufacturer, partnumber, serialnumber, capacity, speed, memorytype, formfactor"`) do (
            set Var!Count!=%%F
            set /a Count=!Count!+1
            :LoopRam
                if "(%%F)"=="" (
                    goto LoopRam
                ) else (
                    echo(%%F >> "%FileName%.txt"
                )
        )
        endlocal
    :: Add systeminfo to file
        cmd /c "systeminfo" >> "%FileName%.txt"
        
:: Add local IP info to file
    echo __________________________________________________________________________________________________________________ >> "%FileName%.txt"
    echo. >> "%FileName%.txt"
    cmd /c "ipconfig /all" >> "%FileName%.txt"

:: Add Drive info to file
    echo. >> "%FileName%.txt"
    echo __________________________________________________________________________________________________________________ >> "%FileName%.txt"
    echo. >> "%FileName%.txt"
    echo Drive Information: >> "%FileName%.txt"
    cmd /c "powershell.exe -c "get-psdrive -psprovider filesystem"" >> "%FileName%.txt"

:: Run script to email file
    if exist ".\ps2.ps1" (PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '.\ps2.ps1'") else (
        echo __________________________________________________________________________________________________________________ >> "%FileName%.txt"
        echo. >> "%FileName%.txt"
        echo Unable to send email of text file. Script file not found. >> "%FileName%.txt"
        goto skipPS2
    )
    :skipPS2

:: End of program
    cls
    echo.
    echo.
    echo.
    echo System information has been retrieved. 
    echo Press any key to exit.
    pause >nul
```

```
# *** ps.ps1 *** Version 1.0 *** 2021-10-22 *** Author: Boogershut ***
# This script adds the Public IP to the text file created by 'Get System Info.bat'.

# Tests connection
    if (Test-Connection 216.146.43.70 -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        # Remove excess garbage from filename for proper formatting
        $filename = gci .\ | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1 | select Name
        $filename = $filename -replace 'Name'
        $filename = $filename -replace '\@'
        $filename = $filename -replace '[{}]'
        $filename = $filename -replace '\='
        # Add html from Public IP webpage
        invoke-webrequest 'http://checkip.dyndns.com/' -UseBasicParsing | Add-Content $filename
        
        # Remove excess html garbage
        $Content = Get-Content $filename
        $Content.replace("<html><head><title>Current IP Check</title></head><body>Current","Public") | Set-Content $filename
        $Content = Get-Content $filename
        $Content.replace("</body></html>","") | Set-Content $filename
    }else {
        # Remove excess garbage from filename for proper formatting
        $filename = gci .\ | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1 | select Name
        $filename = $filename -replace 'Name'
        $filename = $filename -replace '\@'
        $filename = $filename -replace '[{}]'
        $filename = $filename -replace '\='
        
        # Add text to file
        Add-Content $filename 'Unable to get Public IP Address. Was unable to ping webpage.'
    }
```

```
# *** ps2.ps1 *** Version 1.0 *** 2021-10-22 *** Author: Boogershut ***
# This script sends an email with the text file created by 'Get System Info.bat' attached.

# Tests connection
    if (Test-Connection 142.250.141.27 -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        # Remove excess garbage from filename for proper formatting
        $filename = gci .\ | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1 | select Name
        $filename = $filename -replace 'Name'
        $filename = $filename -replace '\@'
        $filename = $filename -replace '[{}]'
        $filename = $filename -replace '\='
        $shortname = $filename.Substring(0,$filename.Length-4)
        
        # Send email
        Send-MailMessage -From 'NAME <EMAIL>' -To 'NAME <EMAIL>' -Subject $shortname -Body $shortname -Attachments $filename -Priority High -SmtpServer 'smtp.google.com'
    }else {
        # Remove excess garbage from filename for proper formatting
        $filename = gci .\ | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1 | select Name
        $filename = $filename -replace 'Name'
        $filename = $filename -replace '\@'
        $filename = $filename -replace '[{}]'
        $filename = $filename -replace '\='
        
        # Add text to file
        Add-Content $filename '__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________'
        Add-Content $filename ' '
        Add-Content $filename 'Unable to send email. Was unable to ping SMTP Server.'
    }
```

Comment: is there a reason to NOT use the `Get-ComputerInfo` cmdlet?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I like the formatting of `systeminfo` a bit better. Plus, I'm not sure if `Get-ComputerInfo` has all the same info I'm pulling from the other commands.

Comment: i would try to stay in one type of scripting lingo instead of mixing .BAT and .ps1 stuff. however, if you can't ... then you can't.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thanks, I like that advice. This is my first time coding and I wasn't sure how to accomplish everything in one language.

Comment: you are most welcome! [*grin*] ///// as an aside ... why are you using such a strange series of replacements on your file names? plus, why are you doing it _twice_? the else test makes sense ... but grabbing the newest file, stripping out unwanted stuff looks like the same process being done 2 times.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I'm not sure... Can you point out the specific spots and if you have a possible correction?

Comment: [1] the blocks that start with `$filename = gci .\ |` seem to do the same thing ... so i would rewrite your code to do that only ONE time. /////  [2] also, what does the file name actually look like? ///// [3] also also, you can chain `-replace` calls. so you could do all the replacements in one chain instead of 4 independent assignments.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey
[1, 3] This is what I came up with with those suggestions, at the top of ps.ps1 outside of the if statement and deleted the others (whole code is too big for a comment) Doing this shortened my code by 11 lines! 
`$filename = gci .\ | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1 | select Name
$filename = $filename -replace 'Name' -replace '\@' -replace '[{}]' -replace '\='`
[2] The filename the bat creates is "Test 1234 - System Info_20211026-081903.txt". The ps.ps1 turns it into "@{Name=Test 1234 - System Info_20211026-081903.txt}".
///// Thanks!

Comment: this `@{Name=Test 1234 - System Info_20211026-081903.txt}` is what you get when "stringify" an object with a single property. what you WANT is not the object OR the property ... you want the value in that property. i think that `$FileName.Name` will give the full name of the file at text.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I changed it to `$filename = (gci .\ | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1 | select Name).Name` and deleted the second line. Not sure if that is the proper way to do it but it works... Thanks for the tips!

Comment: kool! that works even better ... and you are most welcome! [*grin*]

Comment: Get Rid of the Bat file you don't need it except as a wrapper to launch the powershell script more easily, and you can also "compile" the pS script to make it easier to run.